# java - how to send request from jsp page to controller

Tags: spring

this is my controller code

```
<div class="control-group">
<form action="customerRegistrationReport" method="GET" target="_blank"   
  <input type="hidden" id="crID" value="${registration.id }"/>
  <input type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Print" />
</form> 
</div>
```

this is my controller code

```
@Controller
public class CustomerRegistrationJasperController {

    @Autowired
    CustomerRegistrationService customerRegistrationService;

    @RequestMapping("customerRegistrationReport")
    public void customerRegistrationReport(@RequestParam(required=true,value="crID") String crID){      

        //int Id=Integer.parseInt(crID);
        System.out.println("int id is : "+crID);
}
```

It was give me this error on browser

There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required String parameter 'crID' is not present

Comment: Considering your error, you already sending request to your controller, so I'm not sure what is your problem, exactly. What is the value of `crID` input? What is sent in your request parameters when you click on Submit?

Answer (score 0):

@RequestMapping value should start from / char.

Try  `@RequestMapping("/customerRegistrationReport")` instead

Also try to add `name` for the input

```
<input type="hidden" id="crID" name="crID"
```